# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

I am getting

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

error when trying to call the `GetPersonName()` method in my main method.

Can any one explain me why this error is happening ?

Here is my code. Thank You

```
//My Class
class Program
{
    // Main Method
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DMO dmo = GetPersonName();
        Console.Write(dmo.PersonArray[0].Name);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static DMO GetPersonName()
    {
        DMO dmo = new DMO();
        dmo.PersonArray[0] = new Person { Name = "XXXXXX" }; // Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        return dmo;
    }
}


// My Data Model Object
public class DMO
{
    private Person[] _personArray;

    public Person[] PersonArray
    {
        get { return _personArray; }
        set { _personArray = value; }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    private string _name = "";

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be because your class and function are both named DMO? I would use different names to be safe.

Comment: @sachleen - What are you talking about?

Comment: Oops, totally failed at reading the code there. Nevermind my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `DMO` class, you never instantiate your `_personArray`.

When instantiating `DMO` `_personArray` is `null`, so this code:

```
dmo.PersonArray[0]
```

fails, as `dmo.PersonArray` is `null` and you can't access any of its members.

You need to instantiate the *whole* array:

```
dmo.PersonArray = new Person[] { new Person { Name = "XXXXXX" } };
```

Answer (score 1):

This is beacuse your `_personArray` array is null which will always return that error, what you can do for example is to give it a default initialization like:

```
private Person[] _personArray = new Person[2];
```